# PHP Script to send SMS using Nexmo API

Tags: php, sms, vonage

I am looking for a `PHP` script to send `SMS` using `API`'s like `Nexmo` / `Twillio` etc.

Is there any `PHP` script that I use to send quick `SMS` messages using `Nexmo` `API`?

Comment: Each SMS provider has it own rules and API's defined. Most of the time they also provide per populair language an example script. If the provider offers a restAPI then you can google "PHP curl example", it gives about 4 million results.
PS. Please read the next time the rules for posting questions on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nexmo lists two PHP libraries on their [Pre-Built Libraries](https://docs.nexmo.com/index.php/pre-built-libraries) page.  Are neither of those suitable?

Direct links to the two libraries Nexmo recommends:

- [Nexmo-PHP-Lib](https://github.com/prawnsalad/Nexmo-PHP-lib)
- [CodeIgniter-Nexmo-Message](https://github.com/appleboy/CodeIgniter-Nexmo-Message)

Disclaimer - I've never used either of those libs, so I can't vouch for them.

Comment: Any such easy Video tutorial?

Comment: yes, there are.  Have you made any effort to search for them?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can send an sms :)

```
<?php
$url = 'https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json?' . http_build_query([
    'api_key' => API_KEY,
    'api_secret' => API_SECRET,
    'to' => YOUR_NUMBER,
    'from' => NEXMO_NUMBER,
    'text' => 'Hello from Nexmo'
]);

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

API Documentation:

https://docs.nexmo.com/index.php/sms-api/send-message
https://nexmo.github.io/Quickstarts/sms/send/

Answer (score 0):

I've used the Nexmo-PHP-Lib and was able to send an SMS to a mobile in Canada.